# Why so strange behavior of Barrier in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, barrier

There is a layout markup:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         android:paddingTop="24dp"
                                         android:paddingBottom="24dp"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test_top_image"
    android:background="@color/bean_red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    />"

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/test_barrier"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="test_top_image"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test_bottom_image"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/test_barrier"
    />
```

Three elements: red top_image , the barrier under red top_image and blue bottom_image under the barrier. I'm waiting for this picture:

[image]

but I have something other:

[image]

Looks like the barrier was moved up at height of blue image.
What's wrong ? 
Thank you !

Comment: You should add Barrier constraint as well

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya please explain, which constraint should I add ?

Comment: Why do you need the barrier? If it references only one id it's pointless.

Comment: Thanks everybody for attention. That behavior is a bug which was fixed in one of release versions.

Comment: Some strange behavior are solved by [force refreshing the layout from the layout editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650506/barrier-doesnt-set-to-referenceids-in-constraint-layout/55897332#55897332)