# Barrier doesn't set to referenceIds in constraint layout?

Tags: android-constraintlayout, barrier

hey last few days I am exploring about the constraint layout.the concept of barrier I can understand but when i implement I can't get the correct output.

I want to set the barrier in the right direction to reference Id's. But barrier doesn't work.it should set for the views which are nameLabel and passionLabel. please help me. thank you in advance. This is the [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3brZ.png)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_barriers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:text="@string/barriers"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="149dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/arun"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:text="Arun Pandian"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.032"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header" />
    <!--@string/hobbies-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passionLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:labelFor="@+id/etPassion"
        android:text="@string/passion"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/etPassion"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nameLabel" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_italic"
        android:labelFor="@+id/cameraType"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/etName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteY="189dp"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="0"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassion"
        android:layout_width="217dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Developing softwares"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/etName"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etName"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteX="73dp"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteY="225dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="0" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="148dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Arun Pandian"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="0" />
    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="nameLabel,passionLabel"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="411dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for the editing dude @Stefan Becker

Comment: What is the version of constraint layout you are using?

Comment: Turns out it actually works, only the Android studio preview is not able to show it properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this:
> you have to give both edittext start constraint to barrier.
>
> Also when I see in My android studio xml my output is same as you post in your question image. check http://prntscr.com/mkdtgb
>
> But when I see in device it's working

[image]

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_barriers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="barriers"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="149dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Arun Pandian"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header" />
    <!--@string/hobbies-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passionLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:labelFor="@+id/etPassion"
        android:text="passios"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/etPassion"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nameLabel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassion"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Developing softwares"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/etName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:labelFor="@+id/cameraType"
        android:text="namegfhfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdf"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/etName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Arun Pandian"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />


    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="nameLabel,passionLabel" />
    
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by updating the `ConstraintLayout` library

From

`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'`

To this

`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha3'`

Comment: yes, version is the root cause of the problem. thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

The same code was working in one project but not in another, both using the same version of the constraint-layout

If it works on device and but not in the layout editor, then try to force refresh the layout in the editor

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a rendering bug in the Preview in Android Studio 3.3.
The barrier will works at runtime on the emulator.