# Bug in Barrier in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I was using the Barrier helper in the android studio. There was a bug in that barrier not showing in the layout screen even if all the references are set and the direction of the barrier is also set. Please help me.[ScreenShot of The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaB2u.jpg)

code is here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewHeader"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="232dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/header" />
```

This is poster view reference of barrier

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPoster"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewHeader"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,2:3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelinePoster"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewHeader"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.594"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/poster" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelinePoster"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="8dp" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/beauty_and_the_beast"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewPoster"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewHeader" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="8dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bookmark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewHeader"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="March 2017 | PG | 123 minutes"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewPoster"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Rent From R29.99"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelinePoster"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/barrier3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Buy From R129.99"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/barrier3" />
```

//This is the barrier

```
    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageViewPoster"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="411dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="731dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: As we change the action bar setting in the styles file the bug again occurs.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54665897/6021469